# Show $\neg R \vee C, (C \wedge R) \to \neg R, (\neg(R \vee R) \to R)$ are jointly consistent.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Working on P.D. Magnus. forallX: an Introduction to Formal Logic (pp. 183, exercise B. 10).

I would need to find a single row in its truth table where this sentence is true:

$$(\neg R \vee C) \wedge ((C \wedge R) \to \neg R) \wedge (\neg(R \vee R) \to R)$$

However, I've not succeedded in finding one. Perhaps, am I missing something ?

Comment: Perhaps there is a typo in the textbook...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's impossible. For the third to be true, $R$ must be true. So for the first to be true as well, $C$ must be true too. But that valuation makes the second false.

Comment: @F. Zer One might reason differently and still reach the same conclusion.  Since R is true, (C∧R) is false in ((C∧R)→¬R).  But, then C is false.  So, (¬R∨C) is false.